# Error after upgrade to angular 4 ERROR in Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'providers' in null

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

After update to angular 4 I always getting the same error during build with angular-cli:

```
ERROR in Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'providers' in null
```

this is my app.modules.ts:

```
const authenticatedRoutes: Route[] = [
      {
        path: 'app',
        component: TsComponent,
        children: routingConfig
      },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'app/cockpit', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ];

const routes: Route[] = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [StartupActivationGuard] }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    GlobalSharedModule.forRoot(),
    TsModule,
    AuthModule.forRoot(),
    StartupModule.forRoot(),
    MaterialModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ErrorHandler , useClass: TimeShepherdExceptionHandler }
  ],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}


authenticatedRoutes.reduce((routeCollection, route: Route) => {
  route.canActivate = defaultGuards;
  routeCollection.push(route);
  return routeCollection;
}, routes);

const appRouterProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

And here my app.routes.ts:

```
const defaultGuards: any[] = [
  AuthActivationGuard
];

const authenticatedRoutes: Route[] = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'app/cockpit', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'app',
    component: TsComponent,
    children: routingConfig
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'app/cockpit', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

const routes: Route[] = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [StartupActivationGuard] }
];

authenticatedRoutes.reduce((routeCollection, route: Route) => {
  route.canActivate = defaultGuards;
  routeCollection.push(route);
  return routeCollection;
}, routes);

export const appRouterProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

I also work with a sub route in another directory ts/ts.routes.ts:

```
export const routingConfig = [
  { path: 'start', component: StartComponent },
  { path: 'logbook', component: LogBookComponent },
  { path: 'example', component: ExampleComponent },
  { path: 'dev', component: DevComponent },
  { path: 'journal', component: JournalComponent},
  { path: 'cockpit', component: CockpitComponent},
  { path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent}
];
export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routingConfig);
```

Any Idea why I get the error?

Comment: This thread suggests it might be the use of 'default' keyword somewhere, or it could be an incorrect import statement somewhere. Please read here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3826

Comment: already tried nothing found and the disable the 'default' exports has no impact...

Comment: I am too facing this issue ! Error doesn't provide any info on file name or page number.

Comment: I have this issue too. It is weird in that once the app is running making a save in a routes file will make the problem go away. It seems like the first ng-build doesn't build correctly. Then a re-compile fixes it somehow. One thing I noticed is that the order that bundles and chunks are built in is different from the first build to subsequent builds. The subsequent builds have no error while the first one does.

Comment: @HarvP same in my application the subsequent builds success without an error and i can go on with development. really weird.